# Excel 2010 pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

On the left I have the following data from a client, and need to turn into the table on the right. The date columns are dynamic - they vary weekly and the resulting pivot table should react when date columns get added/removed.

If a customer/product has more than one date column with value, the new table should have more than one row to accommodate only one value per row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it appears that you want to "de-pivot" your data.  Here's a situation very similar to yours, with a detailed step-by-step solution:
[de-pivoting](https://superuser.com/questions/252148/i-have-a-sheet-that-has-2-cols-in-one-is-the-name-in-the-other-there-are-one-or/252871#252871)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what pivot tables are for, and see [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/) for a tutorial on how to use them. They wrote instructions better than I can.